# Copying and Pasting from Word to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

When I compose written copy in Word 2010 with boxes and copy and paste to Outlook, the colour of text changes completely.  Also, if I hide the borders on box in Word document, when I paste to Outlook they are revealed again!

On many occasions, the text from Word document jumps about and will not easily be located in Outlook.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Paste Options to keep the source format while copying the data from word to outlook. Please try this option:

1. Keep Source Formatting
2. Use Destination Styles
3. Kept Text Only
4. Merge Formatting:

[image]